# Error while saving Optuna study to Google Drive from Colab

Tags: python, sqlite, google-colaboratory, optuna, gdrive

I can save a random file to my drive colab as:

```
with open ("gdrive/My Drive/chapter_classification/output/hello.txt",'w')as f:
  f.write('hello')
```

works fine but when I use the [Official documentation approach of Optuna](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.create_study.html) using the code:

```
direction = 'minimize'
name = 'opt1'
study = optuna.create_study(sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(),direction=direction,study_name=name, storage=f"gdrive/My Drive/chapter_classification/output/sqlite:///{name}.db",load_if_exists=True)
study.optimize(tune, n_trials=1000)
```

throws an error as:

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-177-f32da2c0f69a> in <module>()
      2 direction = 'minimize'
      3 name = 'opt1'
----> 4 study = optuna.create_study(sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(),direction=direction,study_name=name, storage="gdrive/My Drive/chapter_classification/output/sqlite:///opt1.db",load_if_exists=True)
      5 study.optimize(tune, n_trials=1000)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/optuna/study/study.py in create_study(storage, sampler, pruner, study_name, direction, load_if_exists, directions)
   1134     ]
   1135 
-> 1136     storage = storages.get_storage(storage)
   1137     try:
   1138         study_id = storage.create_new_study(study_name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/optuna/storages/__init__.py in get_storage(storage)
     29             return RedisStorage(storage)
     30         else:
---> 31             return _CachedStorage(RDBStorage(storage))
     32     elif isinstance(storage, RDBStorage):
     33         return _CachedStorage(storage)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/optuna/storages/_rdb/storage.py in __init__(self, url, engine_kwargs, skip_compatibility_check, heartbeat_interval, grace_period, failed_trial_callback)
    173 
    174         try:
--> 175             self.engine = create_engine(self.url, **self.engine_kwargs)
    176         except ImportError as e:
    177             raise ImportError(

<string> in create_engine(url, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py in warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    307                         stacklevel=3,
    308                     )
--> 309             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    310 
    311         doc = fn.__doc__ is not None and fn.__doc__ or ""

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py in create_engine(url, **kwargs)
    528 
    529     # create url.URL object
--> 530     u = _url.make_url(url)
    531 
    532     u, plugins, kwargs = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py in make_url(name_or_url)
    713 
    714     if isinstance(name_or_url, util.string_types):
--> 715         return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
    716     else:
    717         return name_or_url

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py in _parse_rfc1738_args(name)
    775     else:
    776         raise exc.ArgumentError(
--> 777             "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name
    778         )
    779 

ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'gdrive/My Drive/chapter_classification/output/sqlite:///opt1.db'
```

Answer (score 1):

So according to the [official Documentation of `create_study`](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.study.create_study.html#optuna.study.create_study)

> When a database URL is passed, Optuna internally uses SQLAlchemy to handle the database. Please refer to SQLAlchemy’s document for further details. If you want to specify non-default options to SQLAlchemy Engine, you can instantiate RDBStorage with your desired options and pass it to the storage argument instead of a URL.

And when you visit the [documentation of SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html), you find that it uses absolute path.

So all you have to do is to change

```
storage=f"gdrive/My Drive/chapter_classification/output/sqlite:///{name}.db"
```

to the absolute path as:

```
storage = f"sqlite:///gdrive/My Drive/chapter_classification/output{name}.db"
```